# Code Analysis: check if a String parameter of a given function is available in a *.properties file

Tags: code-analysis, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

Consider the Java code:

```
ReadProperty.get("info")
```

And a `my_stettings.properties` file:

```
info=Lorem ipsum
server=computer01
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use a code analysis tool (Checkstyle, FindBugs, PMD...) to check if the `String` parameter of my `get()` method is available in the `my_stettings.properties` file.

```
ReadProperty.get("servers") //should produce a warning
ReadProperty.get("server") //is OK
```

Have you some inputs on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any existing tool for doing this. However there are patterns used on the android platform which could be used for your problem, in this case the **R resource class pattern** which generates a class from property files. So the file `my_stettings.properties`:

```
info=Lorem ipsum
server=computer01
```

should lead to a class like

```
public final class R {
    public static final int info=1;
    public static final int server=1;
}
```

In this case you would use it with

```
ReadProperty.get(R.info);
```

which would not compile if the attribute is not available.

- This answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004518/734687 generates an enum which is almost the same.
- This answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1578106/734687 uses an interface to access the values.
- This question here [Tool for checking Java resource bundles (i18n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065420/tool-for-checking-java-resource-bundles-i18n) asks also for tools and provides a link to http://rscbundlecheck.sourceforge.net/. A German blog entry describes the usage here: http://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/resourcebundle-checking/
- Maven Resource Bundle Check Plugin runs some sanity checks on your resource files, see http://labs.consol.de/projects/maven/maven-rbc-plugin/
- Compiler Assisted Localization provides a compile time check, see http://cal10n.qos.ch/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible or would worth it to develop this functionality.

`ReadProperty.get()` should return with `null` or throw an exception (an `IllegalArgumentException`, for example) if the key is not exist in the properties file and unit tests should check that clients of the `ReadProperty` works well (handles `null` return values properly, for example).